# Entity Framework, two Many to Many relationship to same object using Fluent API

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, entity-framework, many-to-many

I am trying to define two many to many relationship to same object using fluent api.

Here is the simplified model:

```
public class PurchaseRequisition
{
    [Key, ForeignKey("Transaction")]
    public int TransactionId { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<People> RequisitionedBys { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<People> AuthorizedSignatures { get; set; }
}

public class People
{
    [Key]
    public string Id{ get; set; }
    public string FullName { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<PurchaseRequisition> PurchaseRequisitionsForRequisitionedBys { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<PurchaseRequisition> PurchaseRequisitionsForAuthorizedSignatures { get; set; }
}
```

Here is the fluent api code:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<PurchaseRequisition>()
.HasMany(a => a.RequisitionedBys)
.WithMany(b => b.PurchaseRequisitionsForRequisitionedBys)
.Map(x =>
{
    x.MapLeftKey("PurchaseRequisitionId");
    x.MapRightKey("RequisitionedById");
        x.ToTable("PurchaseRequisitionRequisitionedBy");
});

modelBuilder.Entity<PurchaseRequisition>()
.HasMany(a => a.AuthorizedSignatures)
.WithMany(b =>b.PurchaseRequisitionsForAuthorizedSignatures)
.Map(x =>
{
    x.MapLeftKey("PurchaseRequisitionId");
    x.MapRightKey("AuthorizedSignatureId");
    x.ToTable("PurchaseRequisitionAuthorizedSignature");
});
```

What I want is to generate two separate linking tables, but what EF generates is two foreign key columns to PurchaseRequisition in People table and 1 foreign key column to People in PurchaseRequisition field.

Can anyone tell me what might be wrong?

Comment: Mapping looks correct. Did you check in the debugger if the modelBuilder code is ever reached?

Comment: I checked and it seems like my code was not being reached.

Comment: Does you model come from DB-First or Model-First? Especially, does the connection string contain the EDM metadata section? If yes, you must remove it (use a simple connection string without metadata section) to work with Code-First, otherwise `OnModelCreating` won't be called at all.

Comment: Thanks! It's working now. Anyway, I am using code first approach to create the database. I thought that since I made changes to my model classes, it would drop and recreate the database automatically, since that was what I specified in my initializer code. It was only when I made a request to my app that accessed database, it ran the modelBuilder code.

Comment: You are probably only *setting* the initializer (`SetInitializer`). This does not run the initialization. It is run when you use a context instance for the first time to access the DB, or you can force it to run with `context.Database.Initialize(false);`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was fixed.

I mistakenly thought that my database initializer code would drop and recreate the database since I made changes to the model classes and my Initializer class extended DropCreateDatabaseIfModelChanges.

As Slauma suggested, fluent api code was not being reached even though the model has been changed. I was setting the initializer using SetInitializer() method and this code only ran when I used a context instance for the first time to access the DB.